# Overriding functions in other modules in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stub, stubbing, nodeunit

I'm trying to stub a function with nodeunit in a Node.js app. Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do:

In `lib/file.js`:

```
var request = require('request');

var myFunc = function(input, callback){
    request(input, function(err, body){
        callback(body);
    });
};
```

In `test/test.file.js`:

```
var file = require('../lib/file');

exports['test myFunc'] = function (test) {
    request = function(options, callback){
        callback('testbody');
    };

    file.myFunc('something', function(err, body){
        test.equal(body, 'testbody');
        test.done();
    });
};
```

It seems like I'm not overriding `request` properly, because when I try to run the test, the actual non-stub `request` is getting called, but I can't figure out what the correct way to do it is.

EDIT:

To expand on Ilya's answer below, with my example above.

in `lib/file/js`:

```
module.exports = function(requestParam){
    return {
        myFunc: function(input, callback){
            requestParam(input, function(err, body){
                callback(body);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `test/test.file.js`:

```
var fakeRequestFunc = function(input, callback){
// fake request function
}

var file = require('../lib/file')(fakeRequestFunc)(
//test stuff
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nodejs override a function in a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649097/nodejs-override-a-function-in-a-module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, variables declared in one module, cannot easily be accessed from another module. In such cases, you have two common variants:

1) Declare everything you need in every module (not your case, I suppose)

2) Pass parameters to a function

```
var ab = "foo",
index = require('/routes/index')(ab);
```

When you call a function form a module, you may pass it 'request' or any other vars or object you need.

Comment: Hi Ilya, thanks for the answer, but I don't really understand the syntax of that second line, or how to use this to stub a function from another module. What is "index = require('/routes/index')(ab);" doing? How would I use it in my example above?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out with the help of @tim-santeford. Thanks, again, Ilya!

Answer (score 2):

I've run into similar issue. After exploring `request` module code my solution was using `request.get` instead of `request` in my code (do exactly the same). And then stub it in test like that: https://github.com/anatoliychakkaev/resizer-app/blob/master/test/resizer.js#L25

It also possible to stub result of 'require' method in nodejs. Check sources on lib/module.js to manage how to do it. It should be something like:

```
require('module')._cache['/path/to/request.js'] = your_stub
```

But I don't like this solution because it doesn't work in 100% of cases and may stop working in future versions of node (this is not public api), so you should use this way only in case when it's not possible to use other ways of stubbing.