# Is it possible to modify the already declared function in requirejs?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, requirejs-define

There was a task to write an extension that would complement some site functionality. And the function necessary to me looks like this:

```
define("lib/interface/leads/pipeline/unsorted/item", ["require", "jquery", "underscore", "twig", "cocktail", "lib/core/view", "lib/components/mail/api", "lib/components/base/confirm", "lib/components/base/player", "lib/interface/leads/pipeline/unsorted/mixins/unsorted_linking_up", "lib/utils/account/users"], function(e) {
"use strict";
// some code
//.....
return o.extend({
  // more some code
  //....
  acceptClick: function(e) {
          e.stopPropagation(),
          e.preventDefault(),
          this.$el.trigger("unsorted:accept:click"),
          this.model.accept({
              status_id: this.options.statuses[0]
          })
      }
 })
})
```

I have never worked with this framework, and I do not know whether it is possible to somehow rewrite or supplement the function from outside. If possible, I would like to know how.
Thank you in advance!

UPD:
Method requirejs.undef() - not work.

Comment: Yes you could use the code you show in your question. It has a few bizarre characteristics but nothing right out preventing the goal you describe. So there's no problem to be solved in your question. If you have tried it, and did run into a specific issue, then describe that issue and provide the code that replicates it.

Comment: @Louis The problem is that I do not know how to programmatically change this function. Tell me where to look for information?)

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649097/nodejs-override-a-function-in-a-module